# How to connect my gridview to database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am using windows forms and i want to create a method that will simply view all the data depending on the item inside the ComboBox in a [datagridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

```
private void InsertReceipt()
{
        decimal Stub;

        Stub = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text) / 2000;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ticket(CustomerID, Date, Store, Amount, NoStub)" +
                   "VALUES (@CustomerID, @Date, @Store, @Amount, @NoStub) ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", cboName.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", txtStore.Text);
        decimal amount = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amount);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoStub", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Stub;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This are the fields and I need to view all the data depending on the item inside the ComboBox.

Comment: Do you have any error or what?

Comment: bind Gridview, fire Query like `Select * from tb where cols= combox.value` refer:  http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-addupdate-record-using-gridview.html

Comment: Imagine you are another person who is reading this question. Would you understand this question?

Comment: just a Gridview databind.

Comment: It's not a big problem ! 1st your want to learning in google . You can searching in google for how to bind a gridview with database values in asp.net c# .

Comment: I'm using Windows Form,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very general and vague therefor it is difficult to be precise in the answer. If you just want to learn how to use the [datagridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) with windows forms [you can find plenty information](https://www.google.de/search?q=windows+forms+datagridview+tutorial&oq=windows+forms+datagridview) about it online.

I find [dotnetpearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial) a good starting point

```
void FillData()
{
    // 1
    // Open connection
    using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(
    Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
    {
    c.Open();
    // 2
    // Create new DataAdapter
    using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(
        "SELECT * FROM Animals", c))
    {
        // 3
        // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
        // 4
        // Render data onto the screen
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
    }
    }
}
```

If i may recomend that you work through a few tutorials and ask specific question where you are stuck (with error messages and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this method way for Bind Gridview with  data from Database**

```
protected void BindGridview()
{
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=***"))//Connection string
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CustomerID,Date,Store,Amount,NoStub  FROM Ticket where ColumnName='"+ YourDrodownId.SlectedValue +"'", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
YourGridview.DataSource = dr;
YourGridview.DataBind();
con.Close();
}
}
```

Then set the `autogeneratecolumns property` to `false` in our Gridview control   and call this method in inside of your page load or were you want !

And Here is a full sample's with a code !

http://www.dotnetpools.com/Article/ArticleDetiail/?articleId=2

http://forums.asp.net/t/1904884.aspx/1

**Update:**

In Desktop application :

http://www.freedotnetapps.com/sql/database-operations-and-datagridview-bind-in-net-desktop-application/

Comment: Please ,see one more time my answer . I put a link fo DA !